# Foundation background overlay full-width

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make my background color full width, I know how to do this with one row, but in my situation I have 2 row:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this effect:

[image]

What's a good way to do it?

Comment: please share your css+html of what you tried + Version of Foundation.

Comment: You could use gradient as a background color

Comment: foundation version is 5.

Comment: not an easy task. you could detect the position and offset of the two columns with javascript and create two fixed background elements with a low z-index

Comment: I think the idea of @srekoble is pretty good. It's easy, responsive and does not make you mess up your grid in a terrible way.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find how to achieve this :)

Comment: @srekoble Thanks i've managed to do it by applying this on my row :   

-webkit-box-shadow: -1000px 1000px 0px 1000px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    -1000px 1000px 0px 1000px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         -1000px 1000px 0px 1000px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);                    
The only problem is that it activate the scroll when the page load..